# Actionbar setTitle() is working only once in OnPageChangeListener()

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-actionbar

I have used `viewpager` and when the page is changed , the title will be changed based on the position.

This is my code inside `onCreate()`

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_news);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    if(actionBar!=null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    }
    ViewPager pager=findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    final ImageView actionbarImageview=findViewById(R.id.actionbar_news_image);
    pager.setAdapter(new SingleNewsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), newslist));
    int position=getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0);
    pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            final NHBean news = newslist.get(position);
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.setTitle(news.getHeadline());
            } else
                Log.d("status", "actionbar is null");
            new SetImageFromURL(actionbarImageview).execute(news.getImageUrl());
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
    pager.setCurrentItem(position);

}
```

And xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="xyz.NewsActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/actionbar_news_image"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/facebookshare"
                />
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this is my res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources
```

Initially, The title is

```
 <string name="title_activity_news">News</string>
```

When I am launching the activity , It is changed to the  `pager.setCurrentItem(position);` --> this item's headline. When page is changed, The `imageview` image is changed perfectly. But the title is not changed.

And the `actionbar` is not null.

Can anyone please help me? I tried all the post related to actionbar.setTitle(). Unfortunately, I didn't get solution

Comment: Hey i did implement the same code , but the title is changing , did you add this line in your AppTheme inside styles.xml  : <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

Comment: I have added `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>`

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava please check my edited question

Comment: I have added a solution , please check !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1 : Your code is correct . Just add this line to  `app:titleEnabled="false"` in collapsingToolbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```

Solution 2 :

```
final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
```

And do this in your onPageSelected :

```
if (collapsingToolbarLayout != null) {
          collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(news.getHeadline());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it works. But it restricts enlarging text in CollapsingToolbarLayout. Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: Enlarging when you try to scroll down ?

Comment: I said, When I added    app:titleEnabled="false", the title size becomes default.(displayed in toolbar) It is not shown with enlarged size with collapsing layout. Thanks :)

Comment: I tried collapsingToolbarLayout. It worked . Even I have posted this answer.

Comment: Got it . Saw that after posting mine :) . No problem . Happy Coding !

Answer (score 0):

Use your toolbar object inside your on page changed listener:

```
toolbar.setTitle("Your Title")
```

Comment: when I used actionbar, it changed the title only once. But toolbar didn't change that too.

Comment: Can you post how are you doing it?

Comment: if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.setTitle(news.getHeadline()); // replace action bar with toolbar.setTitle(news.getHeadline());
            }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, Finally I found a solution. Instead of using `actionbar`, I tried **`collapsingToolbarLayout`**

```
 CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout=findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
 collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(news.getHeadline());
```

It worked for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
toolbar.setTitle("Your Title");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

call this in your page change listener